# Accessing yield return collection

Tags: c#, generator

Is there any way to access the `IEnumerable<T>` collection being build up by `yield return` in a loop from within the method building the `IEnumerable` itself?

Silly example:

```
Random random = new Random();

IEnumerable<int> UniqueRandomIntegers(int n, int max)
{
    while ([RETURN_VALUE].Count() < n)
    {
        int value = random.Next(max);
        if (![RETURN_VALUE].Contains(value))
            yield return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean access? You can foreach the result, can't you?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear - I meant from within the method building the `IEnumerable` itself. Question updated with clarification.

Comment: You've made yourself a method, that returns you a `IEnumerable` collection. Why on earth wouldn't you be able to use it in a loop?

Comment: @Patrick question is pretty clear, check `[RETURN_VALUE]` in the code. OP: why don't you just use a `List<int>` and `Add()` instead of `yield`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, no.  From the perspective of the method the collection hasn't actually been created.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yeah. The question was modified though, it wasn't clear to me before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There *is* no collection being built up. The sequence that is returned is evaluated lazily, and unless the caller explicitly copies the data to another collection, it will be gone as soon as it's been fetched.

If you want to ensure uniqueness, you'll need to do that yourself. For example:

```
IEnumerable<int> UniqueRandomIntegers(int n, int max)
{
    HashSet<int> returned = new HashSet<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int candidate;
        do
        {
            candidate = random.Next(max);
        } while (returned.Contains(candidate));
        yield return candidate;
        returned.Add(candidate);
    }
}
```

Another alternative for unique random integers is to build a collection of `max` items and shuffle it, which can still be done just-in-time. This is more efficient in the case where `max` and `n` are similar (as you don't need to loop round until you're lucky enough to get a new item) but inefficient in the case where `max` is very large and `n` isn't.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you can shorten this slightly by changing the body of the `for` loop to:

```
int candidate;
do
{
    candidate = random.Next(max);
} while (!returned.Add(candidate))
yield return candidate;
```

That uses the fact that `Add` will return `false` if the item already exists in the set.

Comment: The code can be slightly simplified by using the return value of `Add`, such as `do{} while(! returned.Add(candidate))`. That way there's no need to call `Contains`. Or was there a reason for you to wait until the next iteration before adding the item to the set? Memory space optimization?

Comment: @dcastro: Not particularly. I do think it's clearer to make the condition side-effect-free, but I take your point. Have edited the answer to give both options.